# Is it possible to have different implementations for a function per parameter ranges without if/match?

Tags: rust

I have a function

```rust
fn foo(n: u16) ...
```

I would like to have different implementations without using if or match inside the function

Pseudo Code:

```rust
impl foo(n: u16) for n=0 {...}
impl foo(n: u16) for n=1  {...}
impl foo(n: u16) for n in 2..u16::MAX {...}
```

and then call

```rust
foo(0);
foo(1);
foo(65535);
```

Is this possible? And if it's possible, how can it be used?

Comment: why are you trying to avoid `match`?

Comment: I need to use different asm!() instructions for n=0, n=1 to have accurate cpu cycle control

Comment: @xjnxjn how do you suppose a language (such as Haskell) that has this feature implements this? Do you expect something other than conditional jumps (which an `if` compiles to) if so why?

Comment: Would [const generics](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/2000-const-generics.html) be useful here? In other words, can `n` be known at compile time or only at runtime?

Comment: I have tried to use "const generics", but don't get it to work. struct<const N:u16> ..., impl<0> ..., impl<1> ... impl<2..65535> ... I don't understand the syntax to make different const generics a distinct type.

Comment: "I need to use different asm!() instructions for n=0, n=1 to have accurate cpu cycle control" <- This sounds like you're asking an [XY question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Perhaps you should post a different question for the problem you're actually trying to solve?

Comment: What I mean to ask is:  What problem are you trying to solve where you need precise control over cpu cycles? If you really have this requirement, it might make sense to just write the entire function in assembly and then call the assembly subroutine from Rust. But it's hard to give a good recommendation without knowing the problem you're actually trying to solve.

Comment: May be it is an XY question. My current problem is : at n=0 no instructions at all should be emitted by the compiler, at n=1 exact specified instruction should be emitted, at n>1 normal rust code instruction should be emitted. But my question is also more general ...

Comment: The question was *why*?  Why do you care about the number of instructions emitted in each of these cases?  What is the real world/business problem that you're trying to model/solve here?

Comment: As the existing answers indicate, the answer to your question about different implementations of a function based on the value of a parameter is "no, it's not possible". However, we may be able to help find a solution to your actual real world problem, which is why we ask.

Comment: This sounds a lot like "I don't trust the compiler's optimizations, so I want to write my own." I'd try the dumber version first with a `match` in it and see how it compiles in `--release` mode. You might be surprised, especially if you fuss around with [inline](https://nnethercote.github.io/perf-book/inlining.html) declarations.

Comment: Ok, no it the answer, thx to all. I have to rethink and ask a new question with my "real" problem later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, sorry.

https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/items/functions.html#function-parameters:

> Function parameters are irrefutable [patterns](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/patterns.html), so any pattern that is valid in an else-less let binding is also valid as a parameter

https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/patterns.html#refutability:

> A pattern is said to be *refutable* when it has the possibility of not being matched by the value it is being matched against. *Irrefutable* patterns, on the other hand, always match the value they are being matched against.

https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/patterns.html#literal-patterns:

> Literal patterns are always refutable.

https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/patterns.html#range-patterns:

> Range patterns for fix-width integer and char types are irrefutable when they span the entire set of possible values of a type.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible, in Rust every [function implementation has to have a single function body](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/items/functions.html).